# Sometimes PyDev doesn't recognise .py files as python source files

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Sometimes when I open a python file (.py extension) in the PyDev Package Explorer, that file is opened as a plain text file - without syntax highlighting, breakpoint setting and all the other great PyDev features. I cannot see any differences to other files in the same folder. When I create another .py file (this time PyDev realises that it *is* a python source file), add an `import unrecognised_file` statement with a breakpoint, debug the file and choose to "Step into" the unrecognised file, it suddenly comes good and I can see syntax highlighting and can use breakpoints and all.

After closing the unrecognised_file and re-opening it, it is back to dumb text mode an I can't use the PyDev features.

Any clues about what is going wrong? What is the algorithm for determining if a file is a python file or a text file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this happens (and the association for file marks "Python editor" as the default in the preferences), you can right-click the file and do "open with > other" and choose "Python editor" from the list.

That setting should be persisted for that file later on (what could've happened is that you opened the file as text and Eclipse persists that, so, opening again with the PyDev editor should make the association correct again).

p.s.: the debugger forces opening files with the PyDev editor, but that setting is not persisted as when you open the file through the PyDev Package Explorer (that's why it works when you're in a debug session).

Comment: Seven years later and this answer still helped me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You may check File Associations option.

In Eclipse it can be found in Window -> Preferences, General -> Editors -> File Associations.

*.py files should have Python Editor by default.

Comment: This already has the following two entries, which cannot be changed: 
 - "Python Editor (default) (locked by 'Python File' content type)"
 - "Text Editor (locked by 'Python File' content type)"

This looks to me like the setting has to be done somewhere else, if that default is incorrect. It looks correct to me though as Python Editor seems to be the default. Then again, what could cause it to choose the Text Editor for my .py file?

Comment: Do you have the only one such file which is opened with text editor? If other files are recognized as python scripts by default maybe there is a problem with file name? E.g. spaces after .py extension or something similar. I'd try to rename it to something simple such as a.py.